# How do I decrypt once I have encrypted?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I encrypt the text in the following way :

```
try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        String input = "tester";
        byte encrypted[] = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());

        // PRINT ENCRYPTED TEXT

        System.out.println(new String(Base64.encodeBytes(encrypted))); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

In the above code I encrypt the string `tester`. How do I decrypt it ?

Comment: `DECRYPT_MODE` maybe?

Comment: Is this of any use?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471750/how-do-i-decrypt-message-encrypt-in-here

Comment: How about using AES instead of Blowfish? Blowfish might have been a fine choice 12 years ago, but now it's 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the encrypted string :

```
final String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted)
```

and then decrypt using:

```
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString)));
```